# Where is the Samsung Galaxy setting for answering lock/unlock?

Tags: samsung

My friend told me that every time someone calls, he must unlock the phone. He wondered if we could change that setting. I looked in my own Samsung Galaxy and I could not find the setting. Do you know what we could do to resolve the issue so that my friend won't have to unlock his phone every time somebody is calling? I think that the problem is vendor- or operator-specific looking at [this thread](http://forums.androidcentral.com/verizon-galaxy-s-iii/336746-annoyance-verizon-s3-lock-screen-activated-after-phone-calls-2.html) with a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

lock options for your device, from the Home screen, touch Menu Menu key > Settings Settings Shortcut > Lock screen > Screen lock.W hen you select the Samsung lock feature, Swipe (or the With swipe lock option), additional features become available by opening Settings Settings Shortcut > Lock screen > Lock screen options.For any other query you can check at Samsung India site.